# PHP Mysql select

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select some rows from my database, and generate specific HTML where my selection finds something and other HTML when it does not.

This is my code. The problem is that it always finds no matches:

```
$pos = 0;
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table1 where user = 'user'")
    or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM table2 where id = '"
        .$row['id']."'") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
    $dbpos = $row['pos'];
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        if ($dbpos == $pos) {
            echo 'found<br/>';
        } else {
            echo 'empty<br/>';
        }
        $pos++;
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

I always get `empty`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to `print_r` or `var_dump` $row or $row2?  Also you probably don't have to perform two queries - you can probably do a `JOIN` and just do a single query.

Comment: I'm new to php, I'm trying my best to keep the code simple. This is all I could come up with. If you could be more specific.. :)

Comment: Can you tell us what your data is? My help explain the empty returns

Answer (score 0):

Try making your query something like

```
Select * from table1 
inner join table2 
on table1.id=table2.id
Where table1.user='user'
```

This will do what you want in 1 query

If you get 1 result print found.  If you get 0 then print empty

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to determine if your query has an empty result or how many result was found, you can use mysqli_num_rows and remove your second while loop ($result2).

```
$noofrows=mysqli_num_rows($result2);

if($noofrows==0){

echo "Empty<br>";

}

else {

echo "There are ".$noofrows." record/s found.";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. SQL joins can be very efficient depending on how your tables are structured.

```
//Query the DB for all of the rows in table2 where the table2 id column value
// is equal to the value of the id column value in table1
$query = "SELECT table2.* 
          FROM table1
          INNER JOIN table2
          ON table1.id = table2.id
          WHERE table1.user = 'user'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die(mysqli_error());
```

If you're expecting to return more than one row, the following might come in handy

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $dbpos[$i] = $row['pos'];

    $i++;
}

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
    if($dbpos[$i] == $pos) {
        echo 'found<br/>';
    } else {
        echo 'empty<br/>';
    }
}
```

If not, then simply do this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $dbpos = $row['pos'];
}

if($dbpos == $pos) {
    echo 'found<br/>';
} else {
    echo 'empty<br/>';
}
```

More info about SQL joins [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp).